Dealing with Duplicates
Could we find a way to merge duplicate questions on the same link? I.E. Using Code to make it one really long post with different ways the question was asked with answers all posted together? Or would that be confusing or difficult?

Perhaps you can look at some basic info about merging and some previous discussion about this. (Maybe the tag ([meta-tag:merging]) would fit here - if that's what you're after.)
